# Atmosphere GWT setup with IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, gwt, intellij-idea, atmosphere

I currently have a GWT project running. I have a requirement to add some type of polling into it, to allow my server code to setup a connection to the client. Basically I want to update the the user when they have a new message. The hacky way we have it right now is that the client pings the server every couple of seconds to see if a new message has been added.

In terms of messages working it works fine, but a lot of wasted calls to the server when there are no new messages 95% of the time.

I was thinking of using Atmosphere http://async-io.org/ to set up a connection from server to client, but going through the tutorial and running into some issues.

Background info, I am using IntelliJ to edit the code and run my GWT project. Also I am not using any kind of dependency manager like Maven or Gradle. Most of the setup information uses maven to setup the dependencies you would need.

Does anyone know of any readings or tutorials in how to setup Atmosphere without Maven? Also if anyone knows of another

Comment: If you can provide additional info of what exact issues you are facing it will be little bit easier to address your problem

Answer (score 0):

In your project .gwt.xml file add the following:

```
<inherits name="org.atmosphere.gwt.Client"/>
```

Then add the following libraries to your gwt client classpath (at this time I am using Atmosphere GWT 1.1.0.RC1, but you can use Atmosphere GWT 1.1.0.RC5):

- atmosphere-gwt-client-1.1.0.RC1.jar

And add the following libraries to your server classpath:

- atmosphere-compat-jbossweb-1.1.0.RC1.jar
- atmosphere-compat-tomcat7-1.1.0.RC1.jar
- atmosphere-compat-tomcat-1.1.0.RC1.jar
- atmosphere-gwt-common-server-1.1.0.RC1.jar
- atmosphere-gwt-poll-1.1.0.RC1.jar
- atmosphere-gwt-server-1.1.0.RC1.jar
- atmosphere-runtime-1.1.0.RC1.jar
- atmosphere-socketio-1.1.0.RC1.jar

And that's it,  I think that must be enough to get you started. For examples in GWT you can take a look at this link:

[Atmosphere GWT sample](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere-samples/tree/master/extensions-samples/gwt/gwt20-managed-rpc)

Comment: I added <inherits name="org.atmosphere.gwt.Client"/> to my gwt.xml
I get the following error. 
 Unable to find 'com/google/gwt/rpc/RPC.gwt.xml'
Is there something else I am missing?

Comment: Sorry, what GWT version are you using?

Comment: Currently using GWT 2.8

Comment: My bad, my project was using GWT 2.6 and I had not migrated to 2.7 yet. GWT RPC is deprecated in 2.7,  you may use atmosphere gwt20 client 2.4.3: atmosphere-gwt20-client-2.4.3.jar